# sql - select rows with a distinct value in a specific column

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's assume that I have the following table:

```
   id     player_name     team
   
   1      Gladiator        A
   2      DarkLord         B
   3      Alligator        A
   4      MonaLisa         C
   5      SpongBob         C
   6      Mikasa           B
```

I want to select **one player from each team**, which means that all the selected rows must have a unique value in the `'team'` column. How can I accomplish this in MySQL?

In my example the selected rows should be:

```
   id     player_name     team
   
   1      Gladiator        A
   2      DarkLord         B
   4      MonaLisa         C
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way to do it using a derived table so you select one id per team and join it to the original table.

```
select t.id, t.player_name, t.team
from tablename t
join (select team, min(id) as minid from tablename group by team) x
on x.team = t.team and x.minid = t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be to fetch using a group by criteria. (Assuming your table name is TEAM_TABLE)

```
SELECT * FROM TEAM_TABLE GROUP BY TEAM;
```

This would return the first record occurring for each value of the `team` column.

Comment: This answer is simply wrong and it is sad that it was accepted.  MySQL specifically warns in the documentation that columns in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY` come from arbitrary rows.